# {{ }} is not getting parsed by pyjade as expected with django

Tags: django, django-templates, pug, pyjade

I have line of pyjade

```
 a.js-track(data-track-data="{\"Job ID\":\"{{ job_details|get_or_na:'id' }}\",\"Job Title\":\"{{ job_details|get_or_na:'title' }}\",\"Company Name\":\"{{ job_details|get_or_na:'organization'|get_or_na:'name' }}\"}", data-track-dynamic-attrs="[\"Stakeholder\"]",href="{% url 'job_detail' job_details.title|slugify job_details.id %}")
```

which is being rendered as

```
<a href="/job/operations-manager/b1ac846e-6834-40c4-8bcf-122c093820b1/" data-track-data="{"Job ID":"{{ job_details|get_or_na:'id' }}","Job Title":"{{ job_details|get_or_na:'title' }}","Company Name":"{{ job_details|get_or_na:'organization'|get_or_na:'name' }}"}" data-track-dynamic-attrs="["Stakeholder"]" class="js-track">
```

I expect it to {{ }} being replaced by intended values rather than being rendered with html.
I am using 4.0.0 version of pyjade here as templating language.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `#{value}`
And for the conditions try to create a variable before the line so you can have more control

```
- var condition = inline_condition
p= condition
```